# Copy Local Group Policy Automatically

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I would like to mirror the Local Group Policy across all of my Windows 7 machines.  Which files do I need to export/import, and can I write a script to automate this on every login/reboot/etc?

Comment: which version of win7?,security only or not?,networked or not?

Comment: Ultimate, Security Only?, Networked

Answer (score 2):

For security policies, you can export the policies from a template machine using secpol.msc, then apply them to other computers using secedit:
[Using Secedit.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875542%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

For non-security policies, I've often just found the registry key being set using [gpsearch](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/default.aspx?ref=1) and then then added them to a CMD file executed during startup.  This only works with settings that use the registry provider, but that comprises anything in Administrative Templates.